# How to sort array with 2 fields in Vue?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, vue.js, computed-properties

So I have this table:

[image]

And I use this [vue2 filter library](https://github.com/freearhey/vue2-filters) and I can only sort by a single field using that.

What I wanted to do is to sort the array in descending order using the `score` and `time_consumed` field. The higher the score and shorter the time_consumed, the higher the place.

In the example above, the order should look like;

```
1. 12 | 10141
2. 5 | 15233
3. 5 | 16233
4. 3 | 11495
```

I used the orderBy filter from the library but I can only sort by score using

```
v-for="u in orderBy(users, 'score', -1)"
```

Is there a simpler way to do this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a computed value to sort your scores.

```js
console.clear()

const scores = [
  {
    score: 3,
    time_consumed: 11495
  },
  {
    score: 5,
    time_consumed: 16233
  },
  {
    score: 5,
    time_consumed: 15233
  },
  {
    score: 12,
    time_consumed: 10141
  },
]

new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    scores
  },
  computed:{
    sortedScores(){
      const sorter = (a,b) => b.score - a.score || a.time_consumed - b.time_consumed
    
      return this.scores.sort(sorter)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="score in sortedScores">
      <td>{{score.score}}</td>
      <td>{{score.time_consumed}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

The sorter works on both values because if the scores are equal, it will end up using the time_consumed.